# How to include a condition to check if cell value in column is empty?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

How can I include a condition to check a excel cell column value to see if it is empty or not? I've already mapped the column using linq mapping. When I go to grab the value whether it is null or not in the excel file, i'm getting object not set to reference error. Any help is appreciated. Here's what I got:

```
 public class Test
 {
 public string excelValue { get; set; }
 }

 string excel = @"C:\excel.xls";
 var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(excel);
 excelFile.AddMapping<ExcelClass>(p => p.excelValue, "Name");
 var getvalue= excelFile.Worksheet<excelClass>("Sheet1").ToList();
 return getvalue;

public string GetMyName(List<excelClass> nameValue)
{
//NEED TO CHECK BEFORE SENDING TO A STRING VARIABLE!!!!!

string name = nameValue[1].excelValue.ToString();
return name;
```

}

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelValue)` will return false if there is a value and true if it's null or empty.

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting your code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a method on a null object, whether it is `ToString()` or anythig else.

```
if(nameValue[1] != null)
{
   if(nameValue[1].excelValue != null)
   {
       return nameValue[1].excelValue.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: `HasValue` is only available on nullable value types.

Comment: If i wanted to put that into a method and still use ".excelValue" as it changes, how would I do it? private static string GetName(nameValue, index)? where would the class "excelValue" go in the parameter?

Comment: @NewKidOnTheBlock I don't quite understand. Maybe you could start a new question.